# Scala state monad in for comprehension

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, state-monad

I'm studying Michael Pilquist's excellent state monad lecture [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jg3Uv_YWJqI).  I get stuck at 54 min with two questions.

1. If `ofs` is an `Option[FollowerStats]`, what is the `?` operator?  I
   can't find a ternary operator on Option in Scala 2.10.2
2. How does the last generator put an updated cache (with hit or miss incremented) back into the `State` result of the checkCache method?  The returned `State` seems to be be discarded and the for comprehension seems to only yielding the `Option[FollowerStats]`

.

```
def checkCache(u: String): State[Cache, Option[FollowerState]] = for {
    c <- State.get[Cache]
    ofs <- State.state {
        c.get(u).collect {
            case Timestamped(fs, ts) if !state(ts) => fs
        }
    }
    _ <- State.put(ofs ? c.recordHit | c.recordMiss)
} yield ofs
```

To try and understand I attempted to re-write the for comprehension, but it's not helped.

```
State.get[Cache].flatMap{ c => 
    State.state{c.get(u).collect(...)}.flatMap{ ofs =>
        State.put(ofs ? c.recordHit | c.recordMiss).map{ _ =>
            ofs
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**
I think I've grasped the key to point 2 thanks to the answers.  I didn't realise that that the yield is essentially saying: take the last state `s => (s,())` from the `put` and replace the `Unit` value type with ofs, to get `s =>(s,ofs)`.  I guess the key is realising that the yield isn't literally returning ofs, but it's translated as State.map.

**Update**
Understand the option bit now.  I guess the presentation still uses the implicits from Scalaz although it's deriving the state monad.

Comment: The `Option ? ... | ...` bit comes from an implicit conversion (specifically an implicit class `OptionOps`). You have probably already dealt with implicit conversions such as being able to call `toInt` on a String due to an implicit conversion to `StringOps` - this is much the same.

Comment: At 1:06:12 he actually mentions the option thing.  Should have continued watching, but OCD prevented it.

Comment: Well hopefully the next OCD sufferer watching that vid will find this question, read all the comments, and know to jump straight back to watch the rest of the vid! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First for the ternary operator.

```
ofs ? c.recordHit | c.recordMiss
```

Is to equivalent to:

```
if (ofs.isDefined) c.recordHit else c.recordMiss
```

Or:

```
ofs.fold(c.recordMiss)(_ => c.recordHit)
```

It's provided by Scalaz and implemented as an implicit class ([`OptionOps`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/3e8aad95e3f45eea5dd6cc463fb0e46553fb2d53/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/std/OptionOps.scala)) that provides a `?` method for `Option` that returns a `Conditional` class that has a `|` method. This is a case where I'm not sure the extra concision is worth the confusion, but people use it, so it's worth knowing about.

For the state update, consider the following simplified example:

```
val inc: State[Int, Unit] = for { i <- get[Int]; _ <- put(i + 1) } yield ()
```

It might look at first like we're "discarding" the state and only yielding unit, but the value of `inc` is actually the entire state-manipulating computation (in this case one that doesn't return any relevant or interesting value), including the update.

Answer (score 1):

1. The `?|` operator comes from the boolean syntax of scalaz. Have a look [here at BooleanOps](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/scalaz-seven/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/std/BooleanOps.scala). It's actually 2 functions, first `?` and then `|` on the `Conditional`.
2. The updated cache is actually the result of running the `State` action. If you look earlier in the video, `State` should have been defined as something that, given a state action and an initial state `s`, running the state action with `s` results in a `(a, s2)` which is a pair of: (a) the value computed (represented as `a` in the tuple) from the passed in state and (b) the new state after the action has been executed (represented as `s2`).

Just note that the new `Cache` is not actually computed until the initial `Cache` is run though the monadic action.

Comment: This is the `?` on `OptionOps`, not `BooleanOps`.

Comment: @TravisBrown So true! Apologies.